# Is there anything wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I had a question for a long time that I later solved and shared the answer to, which I believe will be useful to other users. However, the question was downvoted. I would just like to know if there is something wrong with the question.

I think it's just an *arbitrary downvote*, but it may be that my question is really bad and I can not notice my error (if any).

I know it's not possible to know the reason of the downvote, but I wonder if there is any problem with the question.

**Question:** [Retrieve REDIRECT_STATUS with error_page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021456/get-method-url-and-http-status-from-redirect)

How can I improve this question?

Comment: Never change, Meta. Never change.

Comment: @BoltClock excuse me, I did something wrong? if I'm sorry, I could guide me?

Comment: You didn't. Some people on meta just don't like questions about downvotes I guess, even if they're simply asking how to improve their question in general.

Comment: I hope the [latest edition](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30021456/revisions) helps. But really I'm a little discouraged. @BoltClock - Thanks again, good bye :)

Comment: There was more than a single person who disapproved before your comment @Bolt? Oh, well.

Comment: The question does not appear to actually be about PHP programming, it's about how to set up nginx.

Comment: That question is barely on topic.  Like hanging on the furthest outcrop of on-topicness with the nail of your pinkey finger.  People tend to downvote off topic questions.

Comment: @Will Do you recommend that I delete this question?

Comment: I said it's barely on topic, which means it's on topic.  I disagree with .htaccess questions being allowed, but that was decided long ago.  So, no, I don't suggest you delete it.

Comment: @Will The thought you were talking about this question. I'd better ask the serverfault?

Comment: No, as I said "That question is barely on topic."  You'd have to consult SF's stance on .htaccess questions.  Check their Help link and look at their htaccess tag question list.  Server config questions are definitely home there.

Comment: @Will: Perhaps, when someone is not quite understanding you, repeating the same words over and over again is not the most constructive course of action? Just a thought mate.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: SO is for programming questions only, not "any problem a programmer might encounter."  We were originally the latter, but we have gradually shifted to become more and more strict about it over time.  I don't necessarily agree with that change, but it's the policy the community as a whole has decided upon, so as a 20k+ user I use my close-votes to enforce that policy.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, the question you say is off topic, as it is not about PHP, but Nginx. Try to look it from OP perspective - the OP experiences an issues in PHP and it seems that there is an obscure workaround in Nginx that is the issue cause. By the time of asking, the problem is not Nginx related to the OP at all, and it is not the first question to fall into such category. I'd use the self-invented term "shifting topic" for such questions. Take for example the above question: other PHP devs could experience the same and the answer will lead them to the Ngnx fix.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, my point is that if you do `A `and `A` is not working because of `B`, and you do not know about `B` that much; you'd be searching and asking for the problem of `A` rather than directly deciding to check on `B`. I am personally not a PHP developer and I cannot give a clear definition whether the question is easy to solve or not. In case a simple google research could lead to `B` the question should be flagged, but not sure if really off-topic is the appropriate reasoning. If not, then SO will be the resource to lead to `B`, which I belive is part of its purpose.

Comment: Don't pay any attention to upvotes/downvotes, the site is simply broken by achievements in my opinion, so you have here different kind of people like edit-nazis (that one space you posted in the code was completely unnecessary), downvoters, upvoters etc. I wouldn't care too much about that sort of stuff. If you got the answer thanks to someone or thanks to yourself what's the big deal? Don't cry about it and move on, it's not a facebook to start a drama every time someone downvotes you.

Comment: @vove "Don't pay attention" goes against the entire point of the system. Votes are attached to questions and answers **primarily** as a means to discern quality. You definitely **should** pay attention to upvotes/downvotes,

Comment: @TylerH Not necessarily, if you ever asked question you can notice the following: 5 seconds after asking it you have 1 edit (spaces removed) and 1 upvote, after some time let's say you have 3 answers and all of them have +1. The system doesn't work because people are upvoting anything. Different thing with downvotes as they cost you reputation. I don't agree that most upvoted answers are ALWAYS the best. I am sure that many people do that just to get the badges, which is really stupid as they don't give you a thing (or they do?).

Comment: @vove I don't see how that's related to what I said.

Comment: @TylerH If you don't see the connection between flaws of the upvoting system and your rant about how joust it is I cannot help you any further.

Comment: @vove You said to disregard downvotes and upvotes because they are *achievements* and they *break the site*. I said the opposite is true. You responded with an example that does not suggest otherwise. If you can't tell that a +1 vote on an answer means that someone thinks it's good quality, then *no one* can help *you* further.

Comment: Now you are just trying to start a pointless discussion heading nowhere. The point is that the most upvoted answer is not always the best one as you say and in many cases it's caused by people who upvote every thing. I guess to certain point it is determined by badges as in case of achievements some people always try to collect them all. What assures me in that kind of thinking are pointless edits. It surprised me at first but later I have noticed there is a badge for editing questions. Also don't try to use my words against me as you sound douchy, let's act like an adults.

Answer (score 21):

I think the first few sentences could be improved.

Especially, when you mix both application programming and sys-admin as tags (php and nginx server configuration); you have to spell out the question really clearly.

There tends to be a cognitive bias where one thinks that a person reading has more information than they in fact have. Usually, how you frame it determines how quickly another person can grok your question.

Even as simple as:

> I am running Nginx (version number) on Ubuntu (version number) and am trying get the proper redirect status via the Nginx error_page config. In my nginx config file, I have:
>
> ```
> error_page 404 /error.php;
> ```
>
> I would expect it to return XXX but it instead returns YYY....

Just my opinion.... If it's a straight php question, you can usually just jump into the syntax in question.

Comment: Thanks :) - I tried update, see http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30021456/6

Comment: looks a lot better.  A lot is just personal style so don't take anything I say as dogma. I ask a TON of questions and most are of beginner-intermediate variety in new (to me) technologies (currently iOS / Swift). I usually write out the technical part of the question first and then add an intro like 1-2 sentences to give the technical part context. I find that works well because somebody can know right away whether it is in their wheelhouse and also my level of sophistication. Also, the sights are really driven by questions so I feel ok asking a question even if it's possibly answered before.

Answer (score 5):

In your question you have written "this is not working" which is *never* descriptive enough.

You should always try to accompany this along with either what it is doing instead, what errors it is giving, why the result is different to what you expect, a mix of any of these, or something along similar lines.

With all of the formatting you have put into your question, the actual question itself has become lost. It comes down to personal preference and opinion but...

- I see no reason for the "fastcgi file" to be in bold
- The note isn't quoting anything and may look better just being on its own line

Any time I find I am writing a lengthy question I like to leave a tl;dr (too long; didn't read) at the top just so users can determine whether it is worth their time continuing to read (can they answer it).

The most clear thing on your post should always be the actual question.

---

You may find that using the `---` formatting will help you in distinguishing your question from additional (optional) information

Comment: I posted *fastcgi_params file* because of this review:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021456/retrieve-redirect-status-with-error-page/30965981#comment48160421_30021456 But I'm grateful for markup/formating tip.

Comment: I don’t like TL;DR in questions (in answers they can be useful). If an answers contains "TL;DR" it *is* simply too long. I also don’t like lines in question as they do nothing than adding noise.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not descriptive enough and it is extremely poorly written. A user has no idea what problem you are facing, what tools are you using and what you are trying to ask. He simply looses attention by reading the first sentence. If you cannot grab user attention in the first sentence, it is poorly written.

### Suggestions:

---

Replace

> Using .htaccess and ErrorDocument 404 /error.php, if access an invalid
>   url eg.: http://example/css/invalid-file.css:

to

In my .htaccess I have set ErrorDocument as follows

> > ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

if I access an invalid URL for example http://example/css/invalid-file.css, I get the following output

```
REDIRECT_STATUS: 404
REDIRECT_URL: /css/invalid-file.css
REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD: GET
```

My error.php is set as follows

```
echo 'REDIRECT_STATUS: ', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'], PHP_EOL,
     'REDIRECT_URL: ', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'], PHP_EOL,
     'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD: ', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

and so on

That way you carry the user along with you and he can quickly understand what you are asking.

### Conclusion

Some suggestions when asking questions

1. Make question a little bit personalized, what problem *you* are facing?
2. Get a background of the problem and what you have tried and what is not working.
3. Give an a proper insight into the technologies you are using.